# Android: Using OutputStream and InputStream on JSch Channel to pass SSH commands

Tags: java, android, ssh, inputstream, jsch

I managed to build an SSH connection using the Exec Channel from the Jsch library but I want to use a Shell Channel because I need to react to the feedback from the channel. I figured I had to use InputStream and OutputStream or maybe ByteArray I/O stream. How ever setting the streams and then writing and flushing the outputStream doesnt do a thing. Maybe im missing some understanding of how to use the i/o streams.

The code so far looks like this:

These objects are declared in the Activity

```
static Session session;
String sHost;
String sUser;
String sPassword;
boolean entered = false;
ChannelShell channelssh;
OutputStream commandStream;
InputStream resultStream;
```

This is called to start the session, connect to the Server and open the Shell Channel:

```
@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(final String host, final String user, final String password) {
    sHost = host;
    sUser = user;
    sPassword = password;
    final Button connectButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.connectSSH);
    final Button goButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startSSH);
    connectButton.setText("Connect!");

    new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            try {
                JSch jsch = new JSch();
                session = jsch.getSession(sUser, sHost, 22);
                session.setPassword(sPassword);
                // Avoid asking for key confirmation
                Properties prop = new Properties();
                prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                session.setConfig(prop);
                session.connect();
                channelssh = (ChannelShell) session.openChannel("shell");

                commandStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                channelssh.setOutputStream(commandStream);
                byte[] tb = new byte[1024];
                resultStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(tb);
                channelssh.setInputStream(resultStream);
                channelssh.connect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
            if(session != null) {
                if (session.isConnected()) {
                    goButton.setEnabled(true);
                    connectButton.setText("Disconnect");
                    toast("connected");
                } else {
                    toast("connection failed");
                }
            } else {
                toast("session not created");
            }
        }
    }.execute(1);

    entered = true;
    //dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Then when I want to pass a Command that I have as a String I want to call something like this

```
    public String executeRemoteCommand(String command) {
    try {
        commandStream.write(command.getBytes());
        commandStream.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Later this is supposed to return the answer but since I am not even able to pass commands I cannot check the output. Any help on how to use the `InputStream` to pass the answer is apreciated.

Comment: What "feedback from the channel"? Unless you need to talk to an interactive application, you still better use the "exec" channel.

Comment: Yes but thats actually what i want to do. That is why i use Shell and not exec

Comment: Well actually, I was wrong. Even an interactive application should work in the exec channel.

Comment: thats good news but still i have no idea how. Also keep in mind that i dont want to close and open the channel for each new command.

Comment: Why? There's hardly a more cost on opening the channel than sending a new command to the shell channel.

Comment: But i can not react to any prompt when i have to close and reopen the channel every time.

Comment: Prompts of the interactive application? The exec channel has input and output streams too.

Comment: Yes like when you want to go root and are prompted to enter the password for example. Okay fine but how do i use them? In the meantime i have come so far that i can out stream the commands but how do i process the input? What are the commands to access whatever the channel receives from the host?

Comment: Well, if your "interactive" application is `sudo` than you basically start a new shell, within the "exec" channel. So then there's no difference what channel you use.

Comment: Thats just an example. This cant be so hard to do. Just imagine i wanted to build a terminal. How would you do that?